# Sprite changing position on its own?

Tags: unity

I have a simple 2d scene, where I'm trying to have a sprite at x = -8 which I can move up and down. The problem is, when playing the scene, the sprite "jumps" by itself to the middle, x = 0, for no apparent reason. It then only goes back to x = -8 when there is input to move it. How do I get it to stop "jumping" to the middle at the start of every play?

```
using UnityEngine;
public class player1 : MonoBehaviour
{
     Vector2 targetPos;
     public float speed;
     public float step;
     void Start()
     {
         transform.position = new Vector2(-8,0);
     }
     void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKey("w") && transform.position.y < 3.8)
         {
             targetPos = new Vector2(-8, transform.position.y + step);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey("s") && transform.position.y > -3.8)
         {
             targetPos = new Vector2(-8, transform.position.y - step);
         }
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what value does targetPos have on the first frame, before you've given any input?

Comment: Thanks! This just shows how much of a newbie I am! Guess I'll be more careful from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

targetPos is initialised by default to (0,0), which causes the sprite to move to the centre. Add to the start() method `targetPos = new Vector2(-8,0);` which correctly initialises it to the desired position.